# How could I take char input in background in a C program?

Tags: c, windows, console

I am new in programming. I want to make a console C program that moves a character. For example, moving `@` in any direction on console screen dependent upon the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys.

As an illustration, if the user press <kbd>D</kbd>, then character `@` moves right side, for <kbd>A</kbd>, that character moves in left just like in games car moves. I tried using `getchar()` and `getch()`, but it did not worked as I expected. I think there is no way to do this enlighten me if there is any.

Comment: This is operating-system specific unless you're using a library like [NCurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: i am not using any library i am using minGw compiler in code::blocks in windows 10.

Comment: Then you need to read the [Windows-specific documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer).

Comment: what if , for example , you run a double loop printing only spaces , except on the position of your @, and re run it each time you hit W A S D after updating the position of @ ? 
You would print your table multiple time , but if the objective of your homework is just to move a character , maybe this will suffice ? 

If you need on the other hand , to move it everywhere you want on your window , I suggest to take a look at the ncurses library  .